# css margin of link is clickable in firefox, not in webkit

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, margin

Ive got two buttons to cycle through some content they are seperated with a margin off the the left of each button, in chrome and safari this is fine but in firefox the margin is clickable allowing you to go for one button and accidently hit the margin of the other and cycle in the wrong direction. The same also happens if you use padding

Ive attached a jsFiddle of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/JKhjm/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
.proj-nav img {margin: 0 0 0 70px;}
```

to:

```
.proj-nav a {margin: 0 0 0 70px;}
```

In other words apply the `margin` to the links rather than their contents.

Comment: The question is about margin clickable in firefox, but not in chrome

Comment: Yes? The change I've suggested fixes the problem in FF/OSX in my tests. http://jsfiddle.net/JKhjm/2/ The margin is no longer clickable, since it is no longer inside the <a> element.

Comment: The solution is obvious but maybe @sam wanted to know the margin difference in two browsers. Or why is it clickable in FF and not in Webkit?

Comment: @Dipaks I suppose that's possible. The question doesn't actually pose a question, just states an observed behaviour!